# How to properly consume a WCF Web Service in a Classic Xamarin Solution?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm following the documentation on [Consuming a WCF Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/wcf) and need clarification on how best to do this in a Classic Xamarin (not Xamarin Forms) solution that uses a .NET Standard library.

Specifically, I need to understand whether separate API calls must be wrapped in the interface class e.g. ISoapService so that they can be made asynchronously?  The project already as an auto-generated Reference.cs class that documents all the available web service endpoints.  Does the interface class need to include all potential API calls?

How do ensure that my interface class is properly referenced from the Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS projects?  Is there something specifically required aside from referencing the .NET Standard Project from the mobile projects?

I've looked high and low for WCF web service integration with Classic Xamarin but have not found any helpful samples Any links would be helpful.